# UEFI Secure boot key restrictions?

Tags: uefi, secure-boot

Following the instructions here: [Secure Boot - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Secure_Boot#Using_your_own_keys) worked great last year (2016). However, any keys created since the start of 2017 are refused by my Dell Optiplex 7440's UEFI firmware.

I can even set the date on my desktop to 31st Dec 2016 and create a valid Platform Key, but anything created with a later date fails to upload in the Custom Mode Key Management section of the BIOS with:

> Error replacing key. Please make sure that the new key is properly
>   formatted with signature list and serialization headers.

Exactly the same commands are used as before, just the date on the computer used to generate the key has changed:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout PK.key -new -x509 -sha256 -days 3650 -subj "/CN=Platform Key/" -out PK.crt
cert-to-efi-sig-list -g $uuid PK.crt PK.esl
sign-efi-sig-list -k PK.key -c PK.crt -g $uuid PK PK.esl PK.auth
```

Any ideas gratefully received. This also works/fails in the same way on a Fujitsu machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aaargh - Ubuntu 16.04 version of efitools: 1.4.2. Latest version of efitools: 1.7.0. Problem solved!

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer (otherwise your question still appears in the "unanswered" lists).